# How to create unstable font sizes?

Tags: c#, font-size

I have created a TextBox on the code

```
RichTextBox tb3 = new RichTextBox();
```

Then I wrote an other code (in the same void) to change it's font:

```
tb3.Font.Size(FontSize.Text);
```

But the following error appeares : "non-invocable member 'Font Size' cannot be used like a method.

Note: "FontSize" is an ID for a textbox.

How can I do it without creating a new Font?
Please help!

Comment: You can't, you must create a new font.

Answer (score 2):

tb3.Font.Size isn't a method, it is

> public float Size { get; }

and you can't change it so.

if you want to change font see it -> [link1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32114020-9e64-48e5-adaa-af9ee96626ae/change-font-size-in-richtextbox?forum=winforms)
and it [link2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont(v=vs.110).aspx)

you should create new font, for example:

```
tb3.Font = new Font(tb3.Font.FontFamily, 23, FontStyle.Regular);
```